# VS Code .HTML Angular Property Color

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode and i cannot figure out how to get the TypeScript properties to color-code in HTML file.

I have: 
[image: Current VSCode Image]

I intend the color coding as below (purple): 
[image: Required VSCode Image]

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Where does the second screenshot come from? Did you manually edit the colors, or is it from a different editor?

Comment: Hi - Yes, the second screenshot is from WebStorm.